# Xamarin Essentials Geolocation trouble requesting other permissions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, permissions, geolocation

so I'm using geolocation to get the device location and it handles the runtime permissions request for itself which is good and works fine.
However now I'm trying to get permission to read/write external storage and its getting blocked by the geolocation permission request giving the following error

```
W/Activity(21598): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
```

it doesn't matter if i use the xamarin essentials permissions api like this:

```
 private static async Task<bool> CheckAndRequestStoragePermission()
    {
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not granted");
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("granted");
        }
        return status == PermissionStatus.Granted;
    }
```

or doing it in the android main activity

```
 const int RequestPermisionsID = 0;

    readonly string[] RequestPermision =
    {
        Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage
    };
         protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
        {
            if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                RequestPermissions(LocationPermissions, RequestLocationId);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("permissions already granted.");
            }
        }
    }    }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Location permissions already granted.");
            }
        }
    }
```

It always get blocked by the geolocation permission request 
so how can I request permissions at the same time as using geolocation or is there a way to stop it from requesting permission so i can handle it at the same time as the external write permission request

Comment: I have never actually used the GeoLocation from `Xamarin.Essentials` but what I understood from your question is that the plugin request the location by itself, Am I correct as of now? Then what I understand that you want is that you want them to have subsequent permission requests am I correct? Please confirm so that I can answer better

Comment: yep you've got it, it requests permission by itself and i would like to have  subsequent permission requests, cheers

Comment: Why not just request both permissions yourself instead of on relying on the library, that way it would be subsequent and also in your control once it's accepted the code would anyways not trigger whats in the library

Comment: I've tried that too but the library still beats me to the request, perhaps if i request permission before the library is initialised but then i will have to do it in on create, is that safe to do?